# How do I add citric acid to my hard candy without it burning?

Tags: baking, food-science, candy

Every time I try a recipe and add the flavoring and citric, within seconds the citric burns and gives the candy a horrible taste. How or when should I add it so that this won't happen. I'm using a powdered form of the citric acid.

Comment: At what point are you adding it? Can you give us an example of a recipe you're using?

Comment: I think you might need to let the mixture cool a little more before adding the citric acid: https://cheftalk.com/threads/citric-acid-in-hard-candy-makes-it-burn.80275/. I think you can even add the citric acid when folding the candy.

Comment: Maybe the citric acid does not actually burn but play havoc with some other ingredient? Many chemicals that you'd describe as "mildly aggressive" at room temperature are "klingon in a moshpit" aggressive at 160°C :)

Comment: Are you sure youre using citric acid and not cream of tartar?

Answer (score 1):

Colors and flavors, including acid, are added after the candy is taken off the heat.

The syrup is still blisteringly hot (literally) but I've never had powdered acid burn in it off the stove.

If your acid is actually burning in the hot syrup then I would recommend finding a new source.